# click/clickAndWait selenese command fails when used in play framework auto-test mode(headless browser)

Tags: testing, selenium, playframework, selenium-ide, playframework-1.x

while writing some acceptance tests for webapp (playframework based),I got confused by the usage of some selenium commands.

click/clickAndWait works well when i run in browser using this command.

```
play run
```

It fails when i run in command prompt(headless browser) using this command.

```
play auto-test
```

I tried some commands before click like pause,waitForElementPresent,waitForPageToLoad

My code for button is:

```
<button class="btn btn-green" name="Next">
Next
<i class=" icon-chevron-right"></i>
</button>
```

I used following selenese commands

```
click('name=Next') or `clickAndWait('name=Next')`
or click('css=button[name="Next"]')
click('//button[@name='Next']')
```

These commands work in browser mode but **fails** if we run in auto-test mode.

error i get:
for clickAndWait command `Timed out after 30000ms`
for click command it fails in next step `assertTitle` for next page. As actual value is still old page.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Just assign your button an id like `<button class="btn btn-green" name="Next" id="next-button">` and use it `clickAndWait('next-button')`.

Old Answer:

In your HTML markup the name is "next" with only lowercase letters and in your selenese code "Next" starts with an uppercase letter. So these are different values and the tests can't work. Please change "Next" to "next".

Comment: thanks for your help, am sorry for mistyping "Next" as "next" in code. My code is: <button class="btn btn-green" name="Next">
Next
<i class=" icon-chevron-right"></i>
</button>

Comment: thanks for your response, i assigned button with an id but still it doesn't work.